# Name resolution failure when deploying war (Windows)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

When deploying a war file to the webserver TOMCAT says it cannot find files.

The path it is trying to reach is something like:
$TOMCAT\folder\file.xml

but the path were it searchs for the file is

$TOMCAT\folderfile.xml

I can change the names of the files in my folders to the names the tomcat is searching for but that doesn't really solve my problem.

The .war file is from a trusted source (and it works on other computers) so I doubt the problem comes from it.

Comment: The first thing to spring to mind: a hard coded string "C:\\...\\folder\file.xml" with _one_ backslash resulting in an escape sequence with the following char.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it was actually the opposite. The application was using environment variables set on the computer and they needed a final slash.

Comment: Okay, I will click the close button.